# Download Sentinel-2 WMS layer using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, wms, sentinel-2

I want to download Sentinel-2 WMS layer from https://s2maps.eu/ using gdal_translate option. I have an XML file to fetch the image. But I am not getting a proper output. I believe it is due to the XML file which I am not an expert to fine tune properly. I can't find out where I went wrong.

```
<GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="WMS">
    <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    <ServerUrl>https://tiles.maps.eox.at/?SERVICE=WMS</ServerUrl>
    <Layers>s2cloudless-2019</Layers>
    <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
    <ImageFormat>image/jpeg</ImageFormat>
    <Transparent>FALSE</Transparent>
    <BBoxOrder>xyXY</BBoxOrder>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>94.9998611110000013</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>26.9998611110000013</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>97.0001388889999987</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>29.0001388889999987</LowerRightY>
    <SizeX>7201</SizeX>
    <SizeY>7201</SizeY>
  </DataWindow>
  <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
  <UnsafeSSL>true</UnsafeSSL>
  <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,403,404,500,502,503,504</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

The output of `gdal_translate -of GTiff wms.xml sent12.tif` is like:

[image: output]

If I check the pixel size it is not 10m and is nearly around 28m. So how do I get the imagery with 10m resolution?

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: I have attached the output in the link [link](https://we.tl/t-uF5cRwQ8Jr) . I do in command prompt `gdal_translate -of GTiff wms.xml sent12.tif` to get the same output

Comment: It appears that you have swapped your coordinates

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way of doing this...

Do a gdalinfo on the service endpoint

```
gdalinfo "WMS:https://tiles.maps.eox.at/?SERVICE=WMS&"
```

Gives a list of Subdatasets (WMS layers) with example GetMap requests:

```
Driver: WMS/OGC Web Map Service
Files: none associated
Size is 512, 512
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=WMS:https://tiles.maps.eox.at/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=s2cloudless-2018_3857&SRS=EPSG:900913&BBOX=-20037508.342789,-20037508.342789,20037508.342789,20037508.342789&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILESIZE=256&OVERVIEWCOUNT=18&MINRESOLUTION=0.5971642834779395&TILED=true
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=Sentinel-2 cloudless layer for 2018 by EOX - 3857
  ...
  SUBDATASET_22_NAME=WMS:https://tiles.maps.eox.at/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=s2cloudless-2019&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-180.000000,-90.000000,180.000000,90.000000&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILESIZE=256&OVERVIEWCOUNT=17&MINRESOLUTION=0.0000053644180298&TILED=true
  SUBDATASET_22_DESC=Sentinel-2 cloudless layer for 2019 by EOX - 4326
  ...
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Then you can do a gdal_translate on the subdataset like:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -outsize 256 256 "WMS:https://tiles.maps.eox.at/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=s2cloudless-2019&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-180.000000,-90.000000,180.000000,90.000000&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILESIZE=256&OVERVIEWCOUNT=17&MINRESOLUTION=0.0000053644180298&TILED=true" out.jpeg
```

Creates a JPEG and associated out.jpeg.aux.xml file:

[image: JPEG created]

Similarly, for your bounds

gdal_translate -of JPEG -outsize 700 700 "WMS:[https://tiles.maps.eox.at/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=s2cloudless-2019&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=94.9998611110000013,26.9998611110000013,97.0001388889999987,29.0001388889999987&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILESIZE=256&OVERVIEWCOUNT=17&MINRESOLUTION=0.0000053644180298&TILED=true"](https://tiles.maps.eox.at/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=s2cloudless-2019&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=94.9998611110000013,26.9998611110000013,97.0001388889999987,29.0001388889999987&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILESIZE=256&OVERVIEWCOUNT=17&MINRESOLUTION=0.0000053644180298&TILED=true%22) out2.jpeg

gives:

[image: BBOX=94.9998611110000013,26.9998611110000013,97.0001388889999987,29.0001388889999987]

Comment: It is really working well. If I want to convert it in tif and keep the native resolution to 10m how to I do that?

Comment: @GokulAnand for TIFF output you just need to  the `-of GTiff` as you had already

Comment: WMS only give a representation of the native data, so not sure if you'' be able to get native resolution.    You can experiment with bounding box and image size in the GetMap request.